# Transfer with wallet rpc do_not_relay=true do transfer

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transfer

I try to use the `do_not_relay` param with transfer but it is still transferring funds.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"transfer","params":{"destinations":[{"amount":1,"address":"..."}]},"account_index":45,"do_not_relay":true}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I do not want that the funds to transfer, I just want to get the fee for calculating real transfer.

Why does it transfer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters `account_index` and `do_not_relay` are not in the `params` object, so are ignored.